# Google Places API: "Located in" address tag

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to get "located in" part of a place's address with Google Places API? For example:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS1zM.png)

I have tried all the endpoints in Places documentation, but none of them return "Floor 1 - Brea Mall".

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/278743541